# How can I edit data fetched from db in html table ? Flask, Jinja2

Tags: python, html, database, flask, jinja2

I'm afraid the title isn't so clear as I want it to be, but I'll try to explain more detailed:

I had a db's table :

```
class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task = db.Column(db.String(10),index=True)
    descr = db.Column(db.String(300),index=True,unique=True)
    docs = db.relationship('Doc', backref='Task', lazy='dynamic'
```

this query `docs = Task.query.all()`

and some html page with a loop:

```
<table>
{% for doc in docs %}
<tr><td>{{doc.id}}</td><td>{{doc.task}}</td><td>{{doc.descr}}</td><td> 
{% endfor %} 
</table>
```

this all works well and looks like usual html table filled with data from my db (sqlite). Like this, but it's just another table, no matter. 
[image]
Sometimes the data have missing values like the last column in this pic, it's normal because I want to fill that later. How can I implement such functionality ? I've tried many things.. The problem is that i don't know how to get another info from currently edited row to make correct record to database.

For example, lets's take the second row and add some data to last column -> submit. Now i must somehow get from this row '234' or 'sfdfs' to make

```
edit_ task = Task.query.filter_by(task=234).first() or 
Task.query.filter_by(descr=sfdfs).first()
```

get the result of this query and simply add new info to unfilled column and than commit.

I can make different forms, requests and other things, but I just don't understand how to make this function in propper way? Shoul i use JS to get info from table in the template, than transfer it to form and than to python /route function? or there is another decision ? may be this html table must be some kind of WTFotms table.widget form? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/12/14/flask-101-adding-editing-and-displaying-data/ the only way i managed to find. Just don't create an html-table mannualy with cycling , Table Class from flask_table can make it for you and there is also an oppurtunity to make edit link.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/beautiful-flask-tables-part-2) about [Grid.js](https://gridjs.io/). It makes it possible to edit table cells directly on a page without extra Edit links.